# How to resize /dev/shm?

Tags: linux, shared-memory

On `Ubuntu 18.04`, When I run

`$ df -h`,

I see this result:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
tmpfs           3,9G   73M  3,8G   2% /dev/shm
...
```

`/dev/shm` has a 3.9G size.

How could I change the size of `/dev/shm`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. Edit file `/etc/fstab` (with `sudo` if needed).
2. In this file, try to locate a line like this one : `none /dev/shm tmpfs defaults,size=4G 0 0`.

**Case 1 - This line exists in your `/etc/fstab` file:**

- Modify the text after `size=`. For example if you want an 8G size, replace `size=4G` by `size=8G`.
- Exit your text editor, then run (with `sudo` if needed) `$ mount -o remount /dev/shm`.

**Case 2 - This line does NOT exist in your `/etc/fstab` file:**

- At the end of the file, append the line `none /dev/shm tmpfs defaults,size=4G 0 0`, and modify the text after `size=`. For example, if you want an 8G size, replace `size=4G` by `size=8G`.
- Exit your text editor, then run (with `sudo` if needed) `$ mount /dev/shm`.

Answer (score 20):

One time resize:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,size=8G /dev/shm
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same in C/C++ using `mount()` or other api?

Comment: @Sandeep Not sure, maybe ask a new question on it and add its link here.  You could do a system call if your process happens to be running as root...