# GCC - VM Machine - allocate more /dev/shm memory

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to start a VM on google cloud console with more memory in /dev/shm. Thing is the only way I've figured out how to do this is by passing somewhere the argument --shm-size to the docker run command. But I don't know where to do this when creating a VM instance with a specific docker image on Google Cloud Console. Any ideas ? Would it be possible to resize /dev/shm when while running the container ?

Answer (score 2):

You can change size of `/dev/shm` while your VM instance is running (after VM creation) with a command `sudo mount -o remount,size=8G /dev/shm`, also you can use [startup-script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) to apply this command during each boot. Please have a look on my steps below:

1. create a VM instance (optional):

```
gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-a --machine-type=e2-medium --image=ubuntu-2004-focal-v20210223 --image-project=ubuntu-os-c
loud
```

2. SSH into the VM instance:

```
gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-a
```

3. change size of `/dev/shm`:

```
instance-1:~$ df | grep shm
tmpfs            2014932       0   2014932   0% /dev/shm
instance-1:~$ sudo mount -o remount,size=8G /dev/shm
instance-1:~$ df | grep shm
tmpfs            8388608       0   8388608   0% /dev/shm
```

4. add a [startup-script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) (optional):

```
#!/bin/bash
mount -o remount,size=8G /dev/shm
```

5. restart the VM instance, SSH and check `/dev/shm` (optional):

```
$ gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-a
instance-1:~$ df | grep shm
tmpfs            8388608       0   8388608   0% /dev/shm
```

Alternatively you can try to [change /etc/fstab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58804023/12428794) and [create your custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images).